# NET 2.0 project builds from VS2017 but not from the command line

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to build [FluentFTP](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP), which has releases for .NET 2.0, 3.5, 4.0 and .NET Standard. All of the releases build fine within the VS 2017 IDE on Windows 7. However when I try to build using `dotnet.exe`, it crashes with this error:

**"Reference assemblies for framework NETFramework,Version v2.0" were not found**...

[image: error]

My build script looks like this:

```
dotnet --info
dotnet restore -v Minimal

dotnet build -c Release

pause
```

How do I build this successfully from the console?

Comment: Have you tried your luck with the `--framework` option?

Comment: try 2.1.101 SDK: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/sdk-2.1.101

Comment: @magicandre1981 He's referring to .NET Framework 2.0 (about 12 years old), not .NET Core 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear you are missing the .NET 2.0 SDK, here are the links to install it:

**x86**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19988

**x64**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15354

Comment: @Robin Is it the exact same error? I would try restarting if you haven't already.

Comment: Those links are broken and I can't find the updated ones :(

Answer (score 1):

Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build?tabs=netcore2x) the `dotnet build` command-line approach is only meant to support .NET Core builds, not .NET Framework builds.

.NET Framework 2.0 isn't supported by any current build system and it also isn't supported by Visual Studio 2017, so I'm surprised it worked correctly. I believe VS2010 was the last version to officially support .NET 2.0 development. .NET Framework builds rely on msbuild (so does `dotnet build` but with different switches and files).

[Visual Studio 2017 Support for .NET Development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs#a-iddevelopdotnet-avisual-studio-2017-support-for-net-development) states that VS2017 supports:

> - .NET Framework versions 4.7, 4.6.2, 4.6.1, 4.6, 4.5.2, and 3.5
> - .NET Core 2.0, 1.1, and 1.0.
> - .NET Native
> - Mono

Comment: As you can read in the doc you linked, `dotnet build` uses msbuild. Not only that, but it features the `--framework` cmd line option. If you follow the "framework" link in the description of this option, you'll see that .NET framework 2.0 is indeed supported by the .NET Core SDK.

Comment: Almost there, so whats the solution again? Should I switch to MSBuild? Basically it builds fine in VS so if VS uses MSBuild I should do the same?

Comment: I thought `--framework` only supported `.netstandard` targets, which the beginning of the [frameworks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) page actually says, but further down it does indeed list `net20` as an option. Interesting. @RobinRodricks did you try that as elgonzo suggested in the earlier comment?

Comment: I had success with 'MSBuild' where 'dotnet' failed, despite the linked doc saying that 'dotnet' just calls 'msbuild'.  That's with VS2019 and framework 4.7.